# Why do I need reverse proxy with daphne?

Tags: websocket, django-channels, daphne

I red a lot of tutorials about using django channels with daphne and everyone use nginx(or apache, does not matter) as a reverse proxy? Why do I need a reverse proxy? Can't I use just daphne for production?

Answer (score 1):

So from my understanding, it would serve well to use a reverse proxy should you already have predefined apache2 uses, in that case you could simple just use it as a reverse proxy, instead of completing switching over to daphne. The other reason could be because of scalability/load balancing abilities that are available with nginx and apache.

Comment: For example, apache2 does a good job of serving static and media files, which might be difficult/insufficient/unscalable on daphne but doable.